# What is the expected behaviour of `C_wrapKey` API if wrapping key is not provided?

Tags: cryptography, cryptoapi, pkcs#11, cryptoki

In the library that I have developer passes source key and `CK_INVALID_HANDLE` (instead of wrapping key) to `C_wrapKey` API and in return I get success.

I doubt this behaviour. Is this the correct return code?

Comment: I think that you should ask the developer of the PKCS#11 module how this can happen. Note that your title and body were slightly out of sync: an explicit invalid handle is different than passing a handle to a key that doesn't exist (anymore).

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that `C_WrapKey` receives an invalid value for `hWrappingKey` parameter, then it should return `CKR_WRAPPING_KEY_HANDLE_INVALID`.

Comment: Hi Egi, I formatted your question for easier reading. Remarks like "I don't think I fully understand your question" should be a comment instead of being part of the answer. I've used the backticks which can be used to format inline code so that the identifier names can be highlighted. Note that you can always re-edit or roll back if you're not happy about the changes.